# логические операции. Почему именно такой результат?

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему на выходе мы имеем `{}`, а не `100`?

```
console.log([] && {} || null && 100 || '');
```

Comment: а почему на выходе должно было быть 100?

Comment: {} || null ={}

100 || '' = 10

В итоге имеем [] && {} && 100  = 100

Comment: ты выбрал неверный порядок операций. На  самом деле будет `[] && {}` -> `{}` - и все, так как следующие операнды `||` даже вычисляться не будут.

Comment: `|| === or` = ИЛИ... `&& === and` = И..